# How to avoid walking the tree twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I have the following method to initialize a tree:

```
function _initTree(treeObj, options){ 
    treeObj = treeObj || []; 
    if(!zpJSUtils.isArray(treeObj)) throw new Error("Input tree must be an array"); 
    this.tree = treeObj; 
    this.rootNode = treeObj[0]; 
    _buildNodes.call(this, treeObj); 
}
```

The `init` method walks the tree to initialize all objects as nodes:

```
function _buildNodes(treeObj){ 
    traverseTree.call(treeObj, function(nodeObj){
        node = new Node(nodeObj); 
        return true; 
    }, this); 
}
```

The traverseTree method (selected from a switch):

```
function _walkPreOrder(tree, callback, ctx){ 
    tree.forEach(function(node, idx){ 
        var continueWalk = callback.call(ctx, node); 
        if(continueWalk){
            if(node.hasChildren()){ 
                _walkPreOrder.call(this, node); 
            }; 
        }; 
    }, this); 
}
```

The question is this.
I want to calculate the height of the tree on init, which is the number of edges on the longest downward path between the root node and a leaf.
So it seems that in order to calculate the height, I'll have to walk the tree again (to find the level of the deepest nested element).

The format of the json is this:

```
var json = [{ text: "root", children: [
    {id: "id_1", text: "node_1", children:[
        {id: "id_c1", text: "node_c1"}, 
        {id: "id_c2", text: "node_c2", children: [
            {id: "id_c2_c1", text: "node_c2_c1"}, 
            {id: "id_c2_c2", text: "node_c2_c2"}, 
            {id: "id_c2_c3", text: "node_c2_c3"}]},   
        {id: "id_c3", text: "node_c3"}]}, 
    {id: "id_2", text: "node_2"}]}];
```

The problem is that the `_walkPreOrder` *could* accept multiple callbacks (eg array), but that would result in an dubious api (since passing in multiple functions makes the possibility to continue walking the tree when the condition is true/false dubious).

What would be a good way to solve this problem, i.e. to avoid multiple iterations?

Comment: So long as you clearly define the semantics of mixed Boolean results returned by the callbacks (say the walking continues until all callbacks return false), the multiple callback approach doesn't sound horrible.

Comment: I can offer several solutions but they all share a common aspect  - remove your (premature??) optimizations.

Comment: @Amit I'm not sure if I follow. What do you mean premature? Either I have to walk the tree twice or I don't... Encapsulating this in a function seems natural, unless I would write a custom loop every time I want to do something different with the tree.

Comment: @NoahFreitas Actually unless I'm missing something, that shouldn't indeed deliver any problems on second thought. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is that you seem to optimize your algorithm (don't traverse twice, break early via return value) and I assume you haven't yet reached a point where a *simple* implementation is too slow.

Comment: Actually it's the second version of the lib I'm writing since the first didn't satisfy me. I had quite some custom loops and things that can be done better. And these optimizations (avoid unnrcessary iterations, breaking in time) are rather basic is it not? Surely for a tree library it should be optimized as good as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the first time you walk the tree while creating the child nodes, either return or mark each child with its max-height.
2. Then upon visiting all children, compare the maximum of all the child heights, and then mark/return the current node with 1 more than the max height of its children.

Comment: Actually it's the solution, somehow it escaped me. I'll calculate the height and set it as property when building each Node and the height of the root node is then the height of the tree. Thanks!